# Facebook POST using Graph API from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully implemented FBGraphAPI in my iOS app. Here, after logged in , the FB app(I created earlier & gave the app ID in my code) installed and I can POST text or others(image, file etc.) on my wall with the app name. Just Like below,

MY_PROFILE_NAME

about an hour ago via APP_NAME.

Now, I want to POST this same 2 same with MY_PROFILE_NAME & APP_NAME but not on my wall. I want to POST it on another specific wall. This means that whoever log on through my app with their ID and make POST, will be POSTED on that specific pre-defined wall.

I don't know that is it possible or not ??? Plz, help me out...

Answer (score 1):

You can't anymore. Facebook removed the ability to post to friends walls via Graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/#february-2013

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>
> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.